# XMPP - Facebook - How can my client implementation receive messages sent by other client implementations?

Tags: java, facebook, xmpp, smack, facebook-chat

I have implemented a facebook chat client that connect using the Smack API. At this moment, the main features are working well. I send, receive messages, receive typing notifications...
But I have a problem. If I'm talking to someone using my client, I receive the messages I sent to the contact within the facebook's chat. But if send a message to the contact via facebook's chat, my client doesn't receive that message. If the contact answers me, I receive his message, but the dialogue becomes incomplete, since it just shows the messages the contact sent, but it doesn't show the message I sent within another XMPP client.

Since the facebook shows the messages sent by my client, I think it's possible to do the same. I'm really new to XMPP and I need some help to figure out how can I do this.

My code looks like this right now:

Receiving messages:

```
connection.getChatManager().addChatListener(
    new ChatManagerListener(){

        @Override
        void chatCreated(Chat chat, boolean createdLocally) {
            if(!createdLocally){
                chat.addMessageListener(messageListener)
            }
        }
    }
)
```

The message listener just pass the message via push to my Javascript Client.

Sending messages:

```
public boolean sendMessage(String jid, String message){
    FacebookContact contact = mapJIDContact.get(jid)

    try{
        if (contact != null && (connection != null) && (connection.isConnected())) {
            ChatManager chatManager = connection.getChatManager();
            if(contact.chat == null){
                contact.chat = chatManager.createChat(jid, messageListener);
            }
            contact.chat.sendMessage(message);
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
    catch (XMPPException e){
        return false
    }
}
```

The FacebookContact is a class created by me. It stores some contact informations and the Chat, if it was already opened.

EDIT:

I found that this feature I want is provided by this XMPP extension: http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0280.html. I'm trying to find if the facebook chat implements this extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you send an IQ to enable the feature the server replies with a <feature-not-implemented /> error IQ, which as specified [here](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0030.html#info-basic) means it is not supporting XEP 0280. I just checked myself through the Audium XML console.

IQ:

```
<iq xmlns='jabber:client'
from='my.facebook.username@chat.facebook.com/Mac-Pro-di-Michele_65563c5f_4D689E59FB8A5' 
to='chat.facebook.com'
type='set'
id='enable1'>
  <enable xmlns='urn:xmpp:carbons:2'/>
</iq>
```

Reply:

```
<iq xmlns='jabber:client'
from='chat.facebook.com'
to='my.facebook.username@chat.facebook.com/Mac-Pro-di-Michele_65563c5f_4D689E59FB8A5' type='error'
id='enable1'>
  <enable xmlns='urn:xmpp:carbons:2'/>
  <error code='501' type='cancel'>
    <feature-not-implemented xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'/>
  </error>
</iq>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do you know anyway to do what I want? I'm starting to think that this is some internal feature of the facebook. But the android application of the facebook synchronizes the entire conversation, too.

Comment: As far as I know the Facebook XMPP Chat server does not implement many XEPs, and I think the brand applications are using some private API since the public one doesn't allow the developer to _send_ messages. I am trying to build a Mac OS chat client, and I think using both XMPP and Graph API is the only way to receive messages, keep them in sync and be able to send them. Still we have no way to get notified of messages received while the client is offline (that means no push notifications), except from an inelegant infinite loop running on a dedicated server.